# How can I make .NET C# ActiveX plugin work on Mac Safari?

Tags: c#, .net, plugins, netscape

So I've created a plugin for windows working in IE Chrome etc (there is an eazy way to make active x plugin work on Netscape based browsers under windows) how to port it to mac?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use silverlight you can code C# and it will work on mac/safari and mac/firefox 
read here: http://silverlight.net/

Comment: I want TO create a plug in, not to use one=)

Answer (score 0):

Switch to a Java applet.  You won't be able to make an ActiveX control work on anything other than Windows.

Comment: Mono is unrelated -- it's an implementation of the .NET framework and CLR for other operating systems. It's not a replacement for ActiveX on arbitrary platforms.

Comment: MONO allows you to run .NET code on a UN*X system.  AFAIK, it won't allow you to run an ActiveX control in a browser on a UN*X system (though it does include a replacement for the ActiveX web browser control you can use in a Forms app), nor does it include any of the likely APIs that you would use from your ActiveX control in any event.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveX is a Microsoft Windows technology. Even if there were a Safari plugin for it, you would be using APIs which don't exist on the Mac OS, virtually guaranteeing that problems would occur (if it would even run at all). If you want to have a cross-platform browser plugin, use Java applets or another similar technology.